What can cause a Kenwood TS-950S' On Air light to stay on?
While changing microphones on W1BBV's Kenwood, I accidentally pressed a button -- do not know which one -- and now the on air light is permanently on.
How can I undo this condition?

Kenwood TS-950S is the model.

Please use your comment as an answer. I found the REG/SEND button. Everything's fixed. I'll accept your answer if you answer using your comment.

Some radios have a "Send / Receive" switch near the microphone jack. It functions like the PTT but it's a lever switch that stays on, not a button.
From memory, it might be a flat silver plastic switch in a recessed hole, 1/2 inch wide, up/down action. Similar to the main power on/off switch.
